# MYSQL count related rows in 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

```
products table
productid   productname
---------   -----------
 1          product 1
 2          product 2
 5          product 3
 10         product 4
 11         product 5
 12         product 6

accounts_products table
id  productid   accountid
--  ---------   ---------
1   1           accountid 1
2   10          accountid 2
3   2           accountid3

leads_products table
id  productid    leadid
--  ---------    ---------
1   1            leadid 1
2   5            leadid 2
3   2            leadid 3
```

I am trying to count how many total products are in leads_products and accounts_products tables based on the same productid's.

```
Expected result

Product ID    Product Name    Total
-----------   ------------    --------
1             product 1         2
2             product 2         2
5             product 3         1
10            product 4         1
```

I tried so far

```
SELECT p.productid as 'Product ID', 
       p.productname as 'Product Name', 
       COUNT(*) as 'Total' FROM products p
INNER JOIN leads_products l ON (l.productid=p.productid)
INNER JOIN accounts_products a ON (a.productid=p.productid)
GROUP BY p.productname,p.productid
```

Above query counts and display higher number than expected.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: What was wrong with what you tried?

Comment: Test Schema: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8472.  With OP's sample query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8472/1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.productid as 'Product ID', 
       p.productname as 'Product Name', 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM leads_products AS l
        WHERE l.productid = p.productid) + 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM accounts_products AS a
        WHERE a.productid=p.productid) AS 'Total'
FROM products AS p
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8472/5

Alternative approach using JOIN (better performance):

```
SELECT p.productid as 'Product ID', 
       p.productname as 'Product Name', 
       IFNULL(l.count, 0) + IFNULL(a.count, 0) as 'Total'
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT productid, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM leads_products
    GROUP BY productid
) AS l
ON l.productid = p.productid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT productid, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM accounts_products
    GROUP BY productid
) AS a
ON a.productid = p.productid
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8472/33

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of why the OP's query did not perform as expected?

Comment: He's calculating the cross product, not the sum. Instead of 1+1 he gets 1*1, and instead of 1+0 he gets 1*0.

Comment: @Mark your query almost works. It displays every record in products table. If there is no count it displays counts as 0. Any ideas? 
Thank you for your fast reply.

Comment: @librium: Hmm... tricky. If only there were some way to remove rows from a result set... shame that's not possible in SQL...

Comment: Well, I can leave with that I think. Thank you

Comment: @librium: I was joking. :) Use WHERE or HAVING.

Answer (score -1):

I did it with a left join of p.products to preserve all the products then counted the products in each list and added them together. Worked first try. There's probably a billion ways to do this.

```
SELECT p.productid 'Product ID', 
       p.productname 'Product Name', 
       COUNT(a.accountid) + COUNT(l.leadid) total
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN accounts_products a ON p.productid = a.productid
LEFT JOIN leads_products l ON p.productid = l.productid
GROUP BY p.productid
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8472/37

Comment: Add one extra row  and it gives the wrong result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ca24/1

Comment: @MarkByers - Did you check it yourself? I got OP's desired result

Comment: @Scarecrow736: He even linked you to a sqlfiddle demonstrating his point.  -1

Comment: @eggyal - I made my post before there were any answers no need to be an ass

Comment: @Scarecrow736: I was referring to your comment to MarkByers.

Comment: @eggyal - Sorry I didn't understand what you meant by your first comment fair enough